# Export 365 Users Mailboxes Size and Unit in separate columns

Tags: powershell, export, office365, size, export-to-csv

I have good script that export 365 Users Mailboxes Size to csv file.

The results looks like that:

[image]

Today it display the **Total Size** with the **Unit** (KB/MB/GB) **inside** the same column.

[image]

As for the **Total Size (Bytes)**- i dont really need that column.

So, i want to separate the **Total Size** column into 2 separate columns of **Size and Unit** columns.

Like that:

[image]

So at the end, the results will be:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [switch]$MFA,
    [switch]$SharedMBOnly,
    [switch]$UserMBOnly,
    [string]$MBNamesFile,
    [string]$UserName,
    [string]$Password
)

Function Get_MailboxSize{
    $Stats=Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $UPN
    $IsArchieved=$Stats.IsArchiveMailbox
    $ItemCount=$Stats.ItemCount
    $TotalItemSize=$Stats.TotalItemSize
    $TotalItemSizeinBytes= $TotalItemSize –replace “(.*\()|,| [a-z]*\)”, “”
    $TotalSize=$stats.TotalItemSize.value -replace "\(.*",""
    $DeletedItemCount=$Stats.DeletedItemCount
    $TotalDeletedItemSize=$Stats.TotalDeletedItemSize

    #Export result to csv
    $Result=@{'Display Name'=$DisplayName;'User Principal Name'=$upn;'Mailbox Type'=$MailboxType;'Primary SMTP Address'=$PrimarySMTPAddress;'IsArchieved'=$IsArchieved;'Item Count'=$ItemCount;'Total Size'=$TotalSize;'Total Size (Bytes)'=$TotalItemSizeinBytes;'Deleted Item Count'=$DeletedItemCount;'Deleted Item Size'=$TotalDeletedItemSize;'Issue Warning Quota'=$IssueWarningQuota;'Prohibit Send Quota'=$ProhibitSendQuota;'Prohibit send Receive Quota'=$ProhibitSendReceiveQuota}
    $Results= New-Object PSObject -Property $Result  
    $Results | Select-Object 'Display Name','User Principal Name','Mailbox Type','Primary SMTP Address','Item Count','Total Size','Total Size (Bytes)','IsArchieved','Deleted Item Count','Deleted Item Size','Issue Warning Quota','Prohibit Send Quota','Prohibit Send Receive Quota' | Export-Csv -Path $ExportCSV -Notype -Append 
}

Function main(){
    #Check for EXO v2 module inatallation
    $Module = Get-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement -ListAvailable
    if($Module.count -eq 0){ 
        Write-Host Exchange Online PowerShell V2 module is not available  -ForegroundColor yellow  
        $Confirm= Read-Host Are you sure you want to install module? [Y] Yes [N] No 
        if($Confirm -match "[yY]") { 
            Write-host "Installing Exchange Online PowerShell module"
            Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement -Repository PSGallery -AllowClobber -Force
        } 
        else { 
            Write-Host EXO V2 module is required to connect Exchange Online.Please install module using Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement cmdlet. 
            Exit
        }
    } 

    #Connect Exchange Online with MFA
    
    if($MFA.IsPresent){
        Connect-ExchangeOnline
    }

    #Authentication using non-MFA

    else{
        #Storing credential in script for scheduling purpose/ Passing credential as parameter
        if(($UserName -ne "") -and ($Password -ne "")){
            $SecuredPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
            $Credential  = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $UserName,$SecuredPassword
        }
        else{
            $Credential=Get-Credential -Credential $null
        }
        Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $Credential
    }

    #Output file declaration 
    $ExportCSV=".\MailboxSizeReport_$((Get-Date -format yyyy-MMM-dd-ddd` hh-mm` tt).ToString()).csv" 

    $Result=""   
    $Results=@()  
    $MBCount=0
    $PrintedMBCount=0
    Write-Host Generating mailbox size report...

    #Check for input file
    if([string]$MBNamesFile -ne "") { 
        #We have an input file, read it into memory 
        $Mailboxes=@()
        $Mailboxes=Import-Csv -Header "MBIdentity" $MBNamesFile
        foreach($item in $Mailboxes){
            $MBDetails=Get-Mailbox -Identity $item.MBIdentity
            $UPN=$MBDetails.UserPrincipalName  
            $MailboxType=$MBDetails.RecipientTypeDetails
            $DisplayName=$MBDetails.DisplayName
            $PrimarySMTPAddress=$MBDetails.PrimarySMTPAddress
            $IssueWarningQuota=$MBDetails.IssueWarningQuota -replace "\(.*",""
            $ProhibitSendQuota=$MBDetails.ProhibitSendQuota -replace "\(.*",""
            $ProhibitSendReceiveQuota=$MBDetails.ProhibitSendReceiveQuota -replace "\(.*",""
            $MBCount++
            Write-Progress -Activity "`n     Processed mailbox count: $MBCount "`n"  Currently Processing: $DisplayName"
            Get_MailboxSize
            $PrintedMBCount++
        }
    }

    #Get all mailboxes from Office 365
    else{
        Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | foreach {
            $UPN=$_.UserPrincipalName
            $Mailboxtype=$_.RecipientTypeDetails
            $DisplayName=$_.DisplayName
            $PrimarySMTPAddress=$_.PrimarySMTPAddress
            $IssueWarningQuota=$_.IssueWarningQuota -replace "\(.*",""
            $ProhibitSendQuota=$_.ProhibitSendQuota -replace "\(.*",""
            $ProhibitSendReceiveQuota=$_.ProhibitSendReceiveQuota -replace "\(.*",""
            $MBCount++
            Write-Progress -Activity "`n     Processed mailbox count: $MBCount "`n"  Currently Processing: $DisplayName"
            if($SharedMBOnly.IsPresent -and ($Mailboxtype -ne "SharedMailbox")){
                return
            }
            if($UserMBOnly.IsPresent -and ($MailboxType -ne "UserMailbox")){
                return
            }  
            Get_MailboxSize
            $PrintedMBCount++
        } 
    }

    #Open output file after execution 
    If($PrintedMBCount -eq 0){
        Write-Host No mailbox found
    }
    else{
        Write-Host `nThe output file contains $PrintedMBCount mailboxes.
        if((Test-Path -Path $ExportCSV) -eq "True"){
            Write-Host `nThe Output file available in $ExportCSV -ForegroundColor Green
            $Prompt = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell   
            $UserInput = $Prompt.popup("Do you want to open output file?",0,"Open Output File",4)   
            If ($UserInput -eq 6){
                Invoke-Item "$ExportCSV"   
            } 
        }
    }
    #Disconnect Exchange Online session
    Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
}
. main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace line:

```
$Results | Select-Object 'Display Name','User Principal Name','Mailbox Type','Primary SMTP Address','Item Count','Total Size','Total Size (Bytes)','IsArchieved','Deleted Item Count','Deleted Item Size','Issue Warning Quota','Prohibit Send Quota','Prohibit Send Receive Quota' | Export-Csv -Path $ExportCSV -Notype -Append
```

With:

```
$Results | Select-Object 'Display Name','User Principal Name','Mailbox Type','Primary SMTP Address','Item Count',@{Name = 'Total Size'; Expression = {($_."Total Size").Split(" ")[0]}},@{Name = 'Unit'; Expression = {($_."Total Size").Split(" ")[1]}},'Total Size (Bytes)','IsArchieved','Deleted Item Count','Deleted Item Size','Issue Warning Quota','Prohibit Send Quota','Prohibit Send Receive Quota' | Export-Csv -Path $ExportCSV -Notype -Append
```

I have replaced 'total size' with the 2 following calculated properties:

```
@{Name = 'Total Size'; Expression = {($_."Total Size").Split(" ")[0]}}
@{Name = 'Unit'; Expression = {($_."Total Size").Split(" ")[1]}}
```

This splits the value into an array and will put them into the specified properties of "Total Size" & "Unit"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-csplit` (case-sensitive -split) to split the `TotalItemSize` value by the unit. This will create an array of three items. The third item will be the `(# bytes)` value that you are replacing anyway.

```
$Stats=Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $UPN
$TotalItemSize,$Unit = $Stats.TotalItemSize.Value -csplit '(\b[A-Z]+\b)').Trim()[0,1]
```

`$Unit` will now have the unit and `$TotalItemSize` will contain the size without the unit. `Trim()` is to remove surrounding spaces from the formatting.

---

You *could* technically do all of your size manipulations with one line:

```
$TotalItemSize,$Unit,$TotalSizeInBytes = ($Stats.TotalItemSize.Value -split ' ' -replace '\(|,')[0,1,2]
```