# Export and filter 365 Users Mailboxes Size Results Sort by Total Size form High to Low

Tags: powershell, csv, filter, office365, export-to-csv

Continuing from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64683375/export-365-users-mailboxes-size-and-unit-in-separate-columns):

I have Powershell script that exports Mailboxes Size Results to CSV file.
The Results contain "**Total Size**" column that display results, and follow by Name.

However, i want the exported CSV file to filter and display only **"greater then" 25GB** Results, from high to low.

Like that:

[image]

Now, there is the [traditional way](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-01832226-31b5-4568-8806-38c37dcc180e) to use [excel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ghmy5Ehj8E8) to filter to Numbers in the CSV results- **after** the powershell export.

But, i want to have it in the CSV file, so i do not have to do it over and over again.

Here's the script:

```
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [switch]$MFA,
    [switch]$SharedMBOnly,
    [switch]$UserMBOnly,
    [string]$MBNamesFile,
    [string]$UserName,
    [string]$Password
)

Function Get_MailboxSize
{
 $Stats=Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $UPN
 $IsArchieved=$Stats.IsArchiveMailbox
 $ItemCount=$Stats.ItemCount
 $TotalItemSize=$Stats.TotalItemSize
 $TotalItemSizeinBytes= $TotalItemSize –replace “(.*\()|,| [a-z]*\)”, “”
 $TotalSize=$stats.TotalItemSize.value -replace "\(.*",""
 $DeletedItemCount=$Stats.DeletedItemCount
 $TotalDeletedItemSize=$Stats.TotalDeletedItemSize

 #Export result to csv
 $Result=@{'Display Name'=$DisplayName;'User Principal Name'=$upn;'Mailbox Type'=$MailboxType;'Primary SMTP Address'=$PrimarySMTPAddress;'IsArchieved'=$IsArchieved;'Item Count'=$ItemCount;'Total Size'=$TotalSize;'Total Size (Bytes)'=$TotalItemSizeinBytes;'Deleted Item Count'=$DeletedItemCount;'Deleted Item Size'=$TotalDeletedItemSize;'Issue Warning Quota'=$IssueWarningQuota;'Prohibit Send Quota'=$ProhibitSendQuota;'Prohibit send Receive Quota'=$ProhibitSendReceiveQuota}
 $Results= New-Object PSObject -Property $Result  
 $Results | Select-Object 'Display Name','User Principal Name','Mailbox Type','Primary SMTP Address','Item Count',@{Name = 'Total Size'; Expression = {($_."Total Size").Split(" ")[0]}},@{Name = 'Unit'; Expression = {($_."Total Size").Split(" ")[1]}},'Total Size (Bytes)','IsArchieved','Deleted Item Count','Deleted Item Size','Issue Warning Quota','Prohibit Send Quota','Prohibit Send Receive Quota' | Export-Csv -Path $ExportCSV -Notype -Append
 
}

Function main()
{
 #Check for EXO v2 module inatallation
 $Module = Get-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement -ListAvailable
 if($Module.count -eq 0) 
 { 
  Write-Host Exchange Online PowerShell V2 module is not available  -ForegroundColor yellow  
  $Confirm= Read-Host Are you sure you want to install module? [Y] Yes [N] No 
  if($Confirm -match "[yY]") 
  { 
   Write-host "Installing Exchange Online PowerShell module"
   Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement -Repository PSGallery -AllowClobber -Force
  } 
  else 
  { 
   Write-Host EXO V2 module is required to connect Exchange Online.Please install module using Install-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement cmdlet. 
   Exit
  }
 } 

 #Connect Exchange Online with MFA
 if($MFA.IsPresent)
 {
  Connect-ExchangeOnline
 }

 #Authentication using non-MFA
 else
 {
  #Storing credential in script for scheduling purpose/ Passing credential as parameter
  if(($UserName -ne "") -and ($Password -ne ""))
  {
   $SecuredPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
   $Credential  = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $UserName,$SecuredPassword
  }
  else
  {
   $Credential=Get-Credential -Credential $null
  }
  Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $Credential
 }

 #Output file declaration 
 $ExportCSV=".\MailboxSizeReport_$((Get-Date -format yyyy-MMM-dd-ddd` hh-mm` tt).ToString()).csv" 

 $Result=""   
 $Results=@()  
 $MBCount=0
 $PrintedMBCount=0
 Write-Host Generating mailbox size report...
 
 #Check for input file
 if([string]$MBNamesFile -ne "") 
 { 
  #We have an input file, read it into memory 
  $Mailboxes=@()
  $Mailboxes=Import-Csv -Header "MBIdentity" $MBNamesFile
  foreach($item in $Mailboxes)
  {
   $MBDetails=Get-Mailbox -Identity $item.MBIdentity
   $UPN=$MBDetails.UserPrincipalName  
   $MailboxType=$MBDetails.RecipientTypeDetails
   $DisplayName=$MBDetails.DisplayName
   $PrimarySMTPAddress=$MBDetails.PrimarySMTPAddress
   $IssueWarningQuota=$MBDetails.IssueWarningQuota -replace "\(.*",""
   $ProhibitSendQuota=$MBDetails.ProhibitSendQuota -replace "\(.*",""
   $ProhibitSendReceiveQuota=$MBDetails.ProhibitSendReceiveQuota -replace "\(.*",""
   $MBCount++
   Write-Progress -Activity "`n     Processed mailbox count: $MBCount "`n"  Currently Processing: $DisplayName"
   Get_MailboxSize
   $PrintedMBCount++
  }
 }

 #Get all mailboxes from Office 365
 else
 {
  Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | foreach {
   $UPN=$_.UserPrincipalName
   $Mailboxtype=$_.RecipientTypeDetails
   $DisplayName=$_.DisplayName
   $PrimarySMTPAddress=$_.PrimarySMTPAddress
   $IssueWarningQuota=$_.IssueWarningQuota -replace "\(.*",""
   $ProhibitSendQuota=$_.ProhibitSendQuota -replace "\(.*",""
   $ProhibitSendReceiveQuota=$_.ProhibitSendReceiveQuota -replace "\(.*",""
   $MBCount++
   Write-Progress -Activity "`n     Processed mailbox count: $MBCount "`n"  Currently Processing: $DisplayName"
   if($SharedMBOnly.IsPresent -and ($Mailboxtype -ne "SharedMailbox"))
   {
    return
   }
   if($UserMBOnly.IsPresent -and ($MailboxType -ne "UserMailbox"))
   {
    return
   }  
   Get_MailboxSize
   $PrintedMBCount++
  }
 }

 #Open output file after execution 
 If($PrintedMBCount -eq 0)
 {
  Write-Host No mailbox found
 }
 else
 {
  Write-Host `nThe output file contains $PrintedMBCount mailboxes.
  if((Test-Path -Path $ExportCSV) -eq "True") 
  {
   Write-Host `nThe Output file available in $ExportCSV -ForegroundColor Green
   $Prompt = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell   
  $UserInput = $Prompt.popup("Do you want to open output file?",`   
 0,"Open Output File",4)   
  If ($UserInput -eq 6)   
   {   
    Invoke-Item "$ExportCSV"   
   } 
  }
 }
 #Disconnect Exchange Online session
 Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
}
 . main
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Can you please provide [mcve] for what you want to achieve?

Comment: I did [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYyq0.png)

Comment: It is something i can implement in powershell code? if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of an unfortunate scenario, but if you're outputting the results to the file on each iteration, you have 2 options:

1. At the end of the script, read the output file, filter the >25gb mailboxes, sort the objects, then output again
2. Instead of writing the user mailbox to the file each user, save to a
   variable instead. At the end, filter, sort, then export to file

Without going too far into the code...

## Option 1

Might be simplest, as you're working off two input sizes already. After you've retrieved all mailboxes and gotten all statistics, read the exported csv file and filter + sort the data. Then, export the info back to the file, overwriting. Something like

```
$tempImport = Import-CSV $exportCSV | Where-Object {($_.'Total Size' -ge 25) -and ($_.Unit -eq "GB")} | Sort-Object 'Total Size' -descending
$tempImport | Export-CSV $exportCSV -noTypeInformation
```

PowerShell may not like overwriting a file read-in on the same command, hence the saving as a temp variable.

## Option 2

Create a live variable storing all mailbox data, and write the information at the end of the script instead of opening the file to append data each iteration. Then, at the end of the script, filter and sort before exporting.

```
$global:largeMailboxes = @() # definition to allow reading through all functions
```

Then, instead of exporting to CSV each time, add the result to the above variable

```
$tvar = $null
$tvar = $Results | Select-Object 'Display Name','User Principal Name','Mailbox Type','Primary SMTP Address','Item Count',@{Name = 'Total Size'; Expression = {($_."Total Size").Split(" ")[0]}},@{Name = 'Unit'; Expression = {($_."Total Size").Split(" ")[1]}},'Total Size (Bytes)','IsArchieved','Deleted Item Count','Deleted Item Size','Issue Warning Quota','Prohibit Send Quota','Prohibit Send Receive Quota' 
$global:largeMailboxes += $tvar
# 
# Alternatively, only add the mailbox if it's larger than 25GB, to avoid adding objects you don't care about
if ($TotalItemSizeinBytes -ge 26843545600) # This is 25 GB, better to make a variable called $minSize or such to store this in, in case you want to change it later.
{
    # Above code to add to global variable
}
```

Once all mailboxes have been added, sort the object

```
$global:largeMailboxes = $global:largeMailboxes | Sort-Object 'Total Size' -descending
```

Then export as needed

```
$global:largeMailboxes | Export-CSV $exportCSV -NoTypeInformation
```